# Insert datetime.now()

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm setting up an electronic system that reads electric current and send it into db. The time the system reads the electric current is different from when it's sent into the db.

I'm using Python so I use `datetime.datetime.now()`. How do I set the INSERT for it to work?

```
def create_table(self):
    create_table_command = "CREATE TABLE sinal(id serial PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(100), medida float, data arr[] )"
    self.cursor.execute(create_table_command)

def insert_new_record(self, label, measure, time):
    new_record = (label, measure, time)
    insert_command = "INSERT INTO sinal(name, medida, data) VALUES('" + new_record[0] + "','" + new_record[1] + "','" + new_record[2] + "')"
    pprint(insert_command)
    self.cursor.execute(insert_command)
```

This is the error I get:

> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject: type "arr[]" does not exist LINE 1:
>   ...l PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(100), medida float, data arr[] )

Comment: Read up on your database library, string interpolation is a terrible way to put values into the query. And note that you're getting a *Python* syntax error, not a postgres one.

Comment: print the query string before executing the query and check for yourself

Comment: Add `+` after `new_record[2]`

Comment: @Gabriel, either use what @johnsharpe has said. Or you can use the `format` in `python`.
```insert_command = "INSERT INTO sinal(name, medida, data) VALUES('{}', '{}', '{}')".format(new_record[0], new_record[1], new_record[2])```

Comment: Error ocurr in the first function. The table was not created. The message point to type arr[] not existing. Change to accepted postgres types. Timestamp for example. See this: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-timestamp/